# Help with preventing bump mapping from affecting the glossy part of my material, file included

Tags: texturing, node-editor, bump

I'm trying to create two materials while having surface imperfections only on the glossy part. I have uploaded the blend file.
My problem is that I don't know how to make the bump map only affect where the voronoi texture is and not where the glossy part is.
Glad if someone could help, also, if there's a better way to combine textures than what I've done, I would appreciate any suggestions. :)

The blender file is uploaded here:  https://we.tl/t-6nSLW7WZQV

[image]

Comment: Hello, the file is not available, could you please upload it again?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know: Does this work? https://file.io/IMRKVbWxUEdM

Comment: This one should work: https://we.tl/t-6nSLW7WZQV

Comment: So you don't want the kind of finger print to be on the glossy part? Please clarify your question, you say that you want imperections on the glossy part, then you don't want, so what exactly do you want on the glossy part and on the other part?

Comment: Thank you, I will be clearer. I want it as it is now, with fingerprints on my glossy part but not to the other part.

The other part(not glossy) has a bump map that I now see wasn’t connected in the BSDF shader. I want the bump map to ONLY affect the part that is not glossy. I have attached a screenshot. Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: I've added the printscreen in the orginial thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix the b&w mask called *roughness_map.psd* with the *Voronoi Texture* through a *Color > Mix Color* in *Darken* mode:

[image]

Here is the map it gives:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you so much! Im so happy! I never thought of using darken when mixing a b&w mask! That so clever! I was stuck with thinking the mask should only be in FAC :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) ...............